# in_array() do PHP

Tags: php, array

Minha array `$tx` está:

```
Array
(
    [tax_val] => Air bag
)
```

testando:

```
echo (in_array('Air bag',$tx['tax_val'])?'Existe':'Não existe');
```

Retorna:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
>   .....

Testei se é array, recorta ARRAY:

```
if(is_array($tx)) {
    echo '<p>ARRAY</p>';
} else {
    echo "<p>NAO ARRAY</p>";
}
```

Alterando o código para:

```
echo (is_array($tx) && in_array('Air bag',$tx['tax_val'])?'Existe':'Não existe');
```

Não retorna nada.

Preciso que seja ternário, mas não funciona, o que há de errado se tem dois valores no `in_array()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso esta acontecendo porque você esta fazendo a checagem com uma `string`.

```
//in_array('Air bag',$tx['tax_val'])
// é isso que o php está vendo
in_array('Air bag', 'Air bag' );
//                      ^
// ou seja $tx['tax_val'] não é um array
```

Talvez o que você esteja querendo e algo como:

```
$tx = [ "tax_val" => "Air bag" , "outra_key" => "outro_valor" ];

$valores = array_values( $tx );
/// nesse momento $valores  == [ 'Air bag', 'outro_valor' ];

echo "Existe na array: ";
echo in_array('Air bag', $valores ) ? "Sim" : "Não";

echo "\nQual é a Key => ";
echo array_search( 'Air bag' , $tx );

echo "\n";
```

[Exemplo da execução](https://repl.it/repls/CapitalHightechFolders)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, foi de grande valia!